# javascript var from php too long

Tags: php, javascript

in this code I pass a PHP var to javascrip to display it in a div element.
When the string in less than 50 char it works nice but when it is a little bit longen it crashes.
here is my code:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM $table2 WHERE id = '$newsId'";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
$thisNews = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
?>
newsContent = "<? echo $thisNews['news']; ?>";

newsDiv  = "<div class='newsBox'>";
newsDiv += "<div class='newsTitle'><? echo $rowArray[$i]['title']; ?></div>";
newsDiv += "<div class='newsBody'>"+newsContent+"</div>";
newsDiv += "<div class='newsFoot'>autor: <? echo $thisNews['author']; ?> - <? echo $thisNews['site']; ?> - <? echo $thisNews['source']; ?></div>";
box.append(newsDiv);
```

Comment: Which error when *it crashes* ?

Comment: Are there possibly linefeeds or special characters, quotes etc in the db output?

Comment: There was indeed a double quote in the 51th char

Comment: Sounds like you should add that as an answer @lanzz

Comment: Can't you provide whole code to find what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach would be `newsContent = <?php echo json_encode($thisNews['news']); ?>;` — that would take care of encoding any special characters in the string, like quote marks that would terminate your JS string and drop you into code context for the remaining of the string, which is not a good thing.

Comment: And the especially nasty string `</script>`.